# How to replace \u0026 with &?

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I need to change this:

`myid=460\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fr20-xxxx`

...to this:

`myid=460&url=http%3A%2F%2Fr20-xxxx`

Here's what I've tried:

```
String map = "myid=460\\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fr20-xxxx";

p = Pattern.compile("\\u0026");
m = p.matcher(map);

if (m.find()) {
    String ret = m.replaceAll("&");
}
```

...but it cannot find the `\u0026`.

Comment: Take a look at this - http://lexsrv3.nlm.nih.gov/LexSysGroup/Projects/lvg/current/docs/designDoc/UDF/unicode/NormOperations/mapSymbolToAscii.html

Comment: What sort of yucky system are you dealing with that's giving you strings with mixed special character encodings?

Comment: Will `str.replaceAll("\\\u0026", "&")` work for you?

Comment: @anubhava: No, it has to be four backslashes.  The string literal `"\\\u0026"` would become the regex `\&`.

Answer (score 9):

If you must use a regex, then you must escape the backslash that is in the Java string.  Then you must escape both backslashes for regex interpretation.  Try

```
p = Pattern.compile("\\\\u0026");
```

But a simple [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) should suffice (it doesn't use regex), with only one iteration of escape the backslash, for Java:

```
ret = map.replace("\\u0026", "&");
```

Comment: Yes, this works! I believe I tried this way and it didn't work. Now it works. Thanks very much for all.

Answer (score -3):

Doesn't something as simple as

```
"myid=460\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fr20-xxxx".replace("\u0026", "&");
```

work?

Comment: No it wouldn't. The string already contains `&` as the java compiler decodes unicode. What you have is the same as writing `"...".replace("&", "&");`

Comment: The same goes for the original string.  The way you've written it, no replacements would be needed because the string already contains an ampersand.  I edited the question to show how the original string would look as a Java string literal.